# Rails - Array of hashes in Grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm really a new guy to Rails, in my project I want to submit a JSON string to Grape API. As you can see, my JSON has an `user` array that contains many objects. How can I define it in my Grape ?
Thank you

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "first_name":"Brittany",
            "last_name":"Chen",
            "email":"comstock@mailinator.com",
            "phone_number":"+29-46-957-15423"
        },
        {
            "first_name":"Lynn",
            "last_name":"Brooks",
            "email":"jensen@mailinator.com",
            "phone_number":"+84-95-185-00137"
        },
        {
            "first_name":"Claire",
            "last_name":"Paul",
            "email":"mei@mailinator.com",
            "phone_number":"+66-64-893-53401"
        },
        {
            "first_name":"Gemma",
            "last_name":"Carter",
            "email":"malik@mailinator.com",
            "phone_number":"+83-46-325-54538"
        }
    ],
    "service_ids":["1", "2", "3"],
    "auth_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

this is my Grape params

```
params do
    optional :user, type: Hash do
        optional :email, type: String, desc: "user email"
        optional :first_name, type: String, desc: "user first name"
        optional :last_name, type: String, desc: "user last name"
        optional :phone_number, type: String, desc: "user phone number"
    end
    optional :service_ids, type: Array[Integer], desc: "list of service ids selected"
    requires :auth_token, type: String, desc: "authentication_token"
end
```

Comment: I need same, any solution you found?

Answer (score 2):

This is called "Validation of nested parameters" in Grape. In your code, you were actually asking for a `user` hash containing optional parameters `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` and `phone_number`, so not exactly what you were looking for.

> With a block, group, requires and optional accept an additional option type which can be either Array or Hash, and defaults to Array. **Depending on the value, the nested parameters will be treated either as values of a hash or as values of hashes in an array.**

*Source: [https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#validation-of-nested-parameters](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#validation-of-nested-parameters_)*

So in your case, you would have to describe your params like this :

```
params do
  optional :users, type: Array do
    optional :email,        type: String, desc: "user email"
    optional :first_name,   type: String, desc: "user first name"
    optional :last_name,    type: String, desc: "user last name"
    optional :phone_number, type: String, desc: "user phone number"
  end
  # ...
  # any other params
  # ...
end
```

And so each item in the array will be expected to match the fields in the given block.